# Tic Tac Toe using Cartesian coordinate system

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to learn the Cartesian Coordinate System, starting with a basic tic tac toe grid for simplicity, then perhaps moving to chess. I was able to make the following code to start out:

```
board = []

def new_board():
    for row in range(4):
        board.append([])
        for column in range(4):
            board[row].append('_')

def print_board():
    print(board)
    print('  %s | %s | %s' % (board[1][1], board[1][2], board[1][3]))
    print('----+---+----')
    print('  %s | %s | %s' % (board[2][1], board[2][2], board[2][3]))
    print('----+---+----')
    print('  %s | %s | %s' % (board[3][1], board[3][2], board[3][3]))

new_board()
print(board)
print_board()
```

When the list 'board' is printed, it gives the following:

```
[['_', '_', '_', '_'], ['_', '_', '_', '_'], ['_', '_', '_', '_'], ['_', '_', '_', '_']]
[['_', '_', '_', '_'], ['_', '_', '_', '_'], ['_', '_', '_', '_'], ['_', '_', '_', '_']]
```

Which is fine, but my issue is that in order for my commands to match the board (e.g. board[1][2] targeting the 1st row and the 2nd column of the board), I have to have a 'dummy entry' for [0], for both the sublists and the entries in the sublists.

Is there a way to do this without the dummy entries and still have my board list references match the actual board spaces?

Answer (score 6):

- It is a convention in Python to use the `_` variable as the 'throw away variable'.
  In your case you can replace `column` with it.
- Rather than using a for loop with `list.append` you can use a list comprehension.

  ```py
  data = []
  for i in range(4):
      data.append(i)

  data = [i for i in range(4)]
  ```
- When you build an array with all of the items having the same immutable value you can make an array with just one value and multiply the array.

  ```py
  foo = [None for _ in range(4)]

  foo = [None] * 4
  ```
- You should not rely on globals to hold state. There are two solutions:

  1. Pass and return the values from the functions.
  2. Use a class to encapsulate state.
- Strings `%` method for formatting is somewhat archaic and buggy. It should be noted that `str.format` or f-strings are a better alternate with more features.

  ```
  values = (1, 2)

  '%s %s' % values

  '{0[0]} {0[1]}'.format(values)
  '{} {}'.format(*values)

  f'{values[0]} {values[1]}'
  ```
- It is best practice to use an `if __name__ == '__main__'` guard to prevent your code from running if imported by accident.
- Python uses 0 based indexing. I have had no problems with it once adjusted. However if you do you'd be better off not using Python.

  Lua, Julia and R are all languages that use 1-based indexing.

```py
def new_board():
    return [['_'] * 3 for _ in range(3)]


def print_board(board):
    print(
        '  {} | {} | {}  '.format(*board[0])
        + '----+---+----'
        + '  {} | {} | {}  '.format(*board[1])
        + '----+---+----'
        + '  {} | {} | {}  '.format(*board[2])
    )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    board = new_board()
    print(board)
    print_board(board)
```

Comment: `%` buggy? Which bugs?

Comment: @Reinderien By buggy I mean the ability to cause, rather than have, bugs. The exact wording the Python wiki uses is quirks. These resolve around how printf style formatting works with tuples - `'(%s,)' % 1 != '%s' % (1,)`. Additionally there are common problems with dictionaries. Whilst the issues seem fairly simple to solve, if you forget or don't know about them then you get needless errors in your code.

Comment: Makes sense. My choice of words would be _bug-prone_, but shrug.

Answer (score 3):

List indices (coordinates) in most programming languages start at 0.  If you want to present a coordinate system that starts at 1 instead, rather than fighting with the native data structures by adding "dummy" entries and then trying to remember to filter them out, you can make life easier by building an abstraction layer that cleanly separates the "native" representation (i.e. a list of lists) from the interface that you want to use in the rest of your code.  For example:

```
from typing import Tuple

class Board:
    """
    A square game board with a fixed size.  Spaces are accessed by 2D
    coordinates that are numbered starting at 1, so a board of size 3
    goes from [1, 1] (upper left) to [3, 3] (lower right).
    All elements in the board are single-character strings.
    """
    def __init__(self, size: int):
        self._grid = [['_' for _ in range(size)] for _ in range(size)]

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return (
            # Horizontal lines between rows
            '+'.join(['---'] * len(self._grid)) + '\n'
        ).join(
            # The rows themselves
            ' ' + ' | '.join(row) + ' \n'
            for row in self._grid
        )

    def __getitem__(self, coords: Tuple[int, int]) -> str:
        x, y = coords
        return self._grid[y-1][x-1]

    def __setitem__(self, coords: Tuple[int, int], value: str) -> None:
        assert len(value) == 1, "Only single characters allowed!"
        x, y = coords
        self._grid[y-1][x-1] = value

board = Board(3)
board[3, 3] = 'X'
print(board)
```

```
 _ | _ | _
---+---+---
 _ | _ | _
---+---+---
 _ | _ | X
```

In this example, the class `Board` abstracts away the internal list and provides its own interface where spaces are specified as `[1...size, 1...size]` instead of `[0...size-1][0...size-1]`, so you can write code that's 1-indexed without having to account for the difference anywhere but inside the `Board` implementation.

Using the "multiple key" syntax on the getter and setter (i.e. `[X, Y]` instead of `[X][Y]`) will help make it more obvious to readers of your code that this is a custom data structure that doesn't necessarily follow the same conventions as normal lists and dicts, and allows you to use something that looks more like Cartesian notation.

By implementing `__str__` you can control how the object is printed; rather than needing to remember to use `print_board()` when you want to pretty-print the board (and having that output be at odds with `print(board)`, now `print(board)` itself will do the thing you want.

Comment: You have not reviewed the code, only answered an off-topic part of the question.